# Docker registry login fails with "Certificate signed by unknown authority"

Tags: ssl, nginx, docker

I'm am running a private docker registry on ubuntu using S3 for storage.  I'm having issues getting docker login/push/pull commands to work over SSL.  I'm using Nginx in front of Gunicorn to run the registry.  It works without any issues over HTTP, but after switching to HTTPS for a prod system, it throws the following error from the client docker login.

```
Invalid Registry endpoint:  x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I have purchased a rather cheap PositiveSSL certificate from Commodo to use for this. I have ensured the root CA and intermediate CA's are installed on the Ubuntu system running the registry.  The following is my nginx configuration for the server

```
    # Default nginx site to run the docker registry

    upstream docker-registry {
      server localhost:5000;
    }

    server {
      listen 443;

      server_name docker.ommited.net;

      ssl on;
      ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/docker-registry.crt;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/docker-registry.key;

      proxy_set_header Host       $http_host;   # required for docker client's sake
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr; # pass on real client's IP

      client_max_body_size 0; # disable any limits to avoid HTTP 413 for large image uploads


      location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
      }
    }
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get docker to properly recognize the cert, or ignore the certificate warning.  I'm running docker-registry version v0.7.3, the particular client I'm using is Docker version 1.1.2, build d84a070.  on a side note, when visiting the registry in a browser, the cert is properly recognized.  any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For cheap / lesser known certs like the COMODO or StartSSL ones, you need to add the entire certificate chain into the certificate file you are using with nginx.  Many operating systems don't trust the intermediate CAs, just the root CA, so you need to fill in the missing steps between the certificate for your host and the root CA that is trusted by the OS.

In the e-mail you received your certificate with, you should also find links to the intermediate CAs and the root CA.  Open the `docker-registry.crt` file, scroll to the bottom, and append the intermediate CAs and, finally, the root CA certificate for the PositiveSSL chain.  Once you've done that, restart nginx.  You should now be good to go.

Comment: awesome! worked like a charm.  Cert warnings aren't being shown by the client anymore. Thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: Helped, thanks! Howto to make the startssl certificate for Nginx:

https://www.startssl.com/?app=42

Comment: What is the correct certificate chain that you use for nginx ? is there any standard ? I find different order of files to concat in different tutorials.

Comment: @alfonsodev, the order in the PEM file should be:
Web Server Certificate (at the top of the file),
Intermediate CA,
(Possibly 1 or more additional intermediate CAs),
Root Certificate (at the bottom of the file) --

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks @sullivanmatt, it's working now, I found this gist https://gist.github.com/bradmontgomery/6487319  
it works perfectly for me. I want to mention that this error can also happen when the domain is not reachable, so always check that the domain is resolving the right ip .

Comment: I used letsencrypt and using the fullchain.pem as my cert file worked! Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 5):

For RHEL hosts, you can add the CA cert to the PKI CA list on the client host:

```
cp docker-registry.crt /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/docker-registry.crt
update-ca-trust
systemctl restart docker
```

From https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/09/06/adding-your-freeipa-servers-ca-certificate-to-the-system-wide-trust-store-on-fedora-and-rhel/

Comment: This answer is so under rated!, whenever I researched every said to add it to trusted certs, then update-ca-trust, At that point it works in web browser but docker login still will fail. 
systemctl restart docker was the missing piece, https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/certificates/, says you used to have to add certs here /etc/docker/certs.d/ , then back in docker 1.13 they made it so system trusted ca's will be merged, but it requires docker to be restarted.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on mac, simply add the registry to the `insecure-registries` setting in `~/.docker/daemon.json`:

```
{
  "debug" : true,
  "experimental" : true,
  "registry-mirrors" : [],
  "insecure-registries" : ["registry.your.domain.de"]
}
```

In case you do a mistake somewhere (I forgot a comma in the JSON) some issues afterwards with starting up the docker daemon might arise. Namely any docker command throwing an `Error response from daemon: Bad response from Docker engine`. A few restarts and resets later that resolved itself.

*(note this approach will permit the docker client to accept any certificate claiming to be for that domain, including forged certificates on spoofed registries, so should only be used for internal networks you control and if you are not concerned with spoofing or man-in-the-middle attacks)*

Answer (score 1):

If you are using letsencrypt and nginx, just change the `ssl_certificate` key from `cert.pem` to `fullchain.pem`.

Comment: it is useful when using let's encrypt