# docker client can't read from both "docker private registry" and "online docker registry" if custom ssl certificate are used

Tags: docker

Docker version 1.2.0, build 2a2f26c/1.2.0,

docker registry 0.8.1

i setup docker private registry on cenots7 and created my custom ssl cert. when I try to access my docker registry using https I get `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`. i found a solution for this by placing the cert file under `"/etc/pki/tls/certs"` then do

`"update-ca-trust"`

`"service docker restart"`

now it started to read my certificate.i can login and pull and push to docker private registry

`"https://localdockerregistry"`.

now when i tries to read from online docker registry(https://index.docker.io/v1/search?q=centos) like

`"docker search centos"`

i get

`"Error response from daemon: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/search?q=centos: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"`

i exported docker.io cert from firefox brower and put it under "/etc/pki/tls/certs" then do `"update-ca-trust"` and `"service docker restart"` but same error. it looks like docker client cant decide which cert to use for which repository.

Any ideas how we can fix "x509: certificate signed by unknown authority" for online docker registry while using your own docker private registry.

Answer (score 3):

The correct place to put the certificate is on the machine running your docker daemon (not the client) in this location: `/etc/docker/certs.d/my.registry.com:5000/ca.crt` where *my.registry.com:5000* is the address of your private registry and `:5000` is the port where your registry is reachable. If the path `/etc/docker/certs.d/` does not exist, you should create it -- that is where the Docker daemon will look by default.

This way you can have a private certificate per private registry and not affect the public registry.

This is per the docs on http://docs.docker.com/reference/api/registry_api/

Comment: Sorry i forget to mentioned earlier, i am running docker registry behind nginx. so nginx is listening on 443 and forward the request to localhost:5000. so do i need to place cert on docker?? secondly i am running docker-registry 0.8.1 tag. and install using pip install so its not running as service and dont have directory /etc/docker/certs.d/. do i need to create that manually?? Thanks

Comment: Hi Andy,

I have a docker (v1) registry running inside a docker container. How do I get it to use TLS? Do I need to copy the certs on the machine that is running the docker image with the registry, or use the Dockerfile to copy the certificates into the docker container running the registry?

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem with a docker registry running in a container behind a Nginx proxy with a StartSSL certificate.

In that case you have to append the intermediate ca certs to the nginx ssl certificate, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25006442/1130611